# Web3.js: Subscribe logs to get new contracts

Tags: web3js, javascript

I want to create a script that always notifies me if a new contract is created. My idea was to look for the "PairCreated" function. To validate if that is correct I have tested it with a simple RPC request to my [Ankr](https://www.ankr.com/) endpoint with this params:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "method": "eth_getLogs",
    "params": [{
        "fromBlock": "0x5B98A9",
        "toBlock": "0x5B98AA",
        "topics": [
            "0x0d3648bd0f6ba80134a33ba9275ac585d9d315f0ad8355cddefde31afa28d0e9"
        ]
    }]
}
```

It gives me this result:

```
{
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "id": 1,
    "result": [
        {
            "address": "0xbcfccbde45ce874adcb698cc183debcf17952812",
            "topics": [
                "0x0d3648bd0f6ba80134a33ba9275ac585d9d315f0ad8355cddefde31afa28d0e9",
                "0x00000000000000000000000086c3e4ffacdb3af628ef985a518cd6ee22a22b28",
                "0x000000000000000000000000bb4cdb9cbd36b01bd1cbaebf2de08d9173bc095c"
            ],
            "data": "0x00000000000000000000000042e32b5bdf0f249aefbee0f604be25e8fc81ac520000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000004d0e",
            "blockNumber": "0x5b98a9",
            "transactionHash": "0x83c03c35721f17e20af8e76e3c3fc29e9b8c20d3dde1e2a648f3556432d2c9ed",
            "transactionIndex": "0x15",
            "blockHash": "0xa400f21ed242eb893823d7c0e6bde7c9a4836c4e397128022a19a82fb2a0273d",
            "logIndex": "0x73",
            "removed": false
        }
    ]
}
```

The contract address in this case is "0x86c3e4ffacdb3af628ef985a518cd6ee22a22b28" (you can get it from results[0].topics[1]).

**First question:** Is this the correct way to get all contract addresses? Or are there contracts without a "PairCreated" log?

With this request I could determine the addresses of a certain block. Now I want to subscribe the logs to get all new contracts. I tried it like this with web3.js:

```
web3.eth.subscribe('logs', {
    topics: [
        // Pair created
        "0x0d3648bd0f6ba80134a33ba9275ac585d9d315f0ad8355cddefde31afa28d0e9"
    ]
}, (error, log) => {
    if (error) {
        console.log(error);
        process.exit(1);
    }

    console.log(log);
}).on("connected", (subscriptionId) => {
    console.log(`Connected with ID: ${subscriptionId}`);
}).on("data", (log) => {
    console.log(log);
}).on("error", console.error);
```

I have been running the script for a few hours now, but have not received a log yet. Maybe no contract was actually created in that time, but that would surprise me.

**Second question:** Is it possible that something is not yet correct here? How else do I always get the latest contracts?